# Microstack on Ubuntu 19.10 eaon

Tags: rabbitmq

On Ubuntu 19.10 eaon:

```
$ sudo snap install microstack --classic --edge
$ sudo microstack.init
```

Stalls on rabbitmq.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You are using the bleeding edge channel version of this snap. This may explain why it is causing you issues. Maybe you should consider beta or stable instead?

Comment: @DanielMassey for me weirdly rabbitmq somehow worked on edge but not candidate

Comment: According to the [official website](https://microstack.run), "MicroStack requires at least 8 GB RAM and a multi-core processor." If it is hanging at a particular stage, it is probably due to insufficient hardware. How much RAM is in your computer and what CPU are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://microstack.run/#get-started use:

```
snap install microstack --devmode --edge
microstack.init --auto
```

Comment: Because you did not use any [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), your answer rendered both lines on a single line, making your answer invalid.  Please proofread your answers before and after submitting.